# Radgrid delete command error "Object must implement IConvertible"

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asp.net-membership, radgrid

I am using Radgrid to manage the membership.
I want to use the delete command to delete a use from database,
but when I click the delete button I keep getting this error:

> Object must implement IConvertible.

The weird thing is that the deletion mechanism works; my user is no longer available.
What could cause the error?

Here is my code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupPanelPosition="Top" Skin="Black" 
        AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True" OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid1_DeleteCommand">
  <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="UserId">
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserId" DataType="System.Guid" FilterControlAltText="Filter UserId column" HeaderText="UserId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="UserId" UniqueName="UserId" Visible="false">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="IsApproved" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter IsApproved column" HeaderText="????? ?????" SortExpression="IsApproved" UniqueName="IsApproved">
      </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
      <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="IsLockedOut" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter IsLockedOut column" HeaderText="IsLockedOut" SortExpression="IsLockedOut" UniqueName="IsLockedOut">
      </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserName" FilterControlAltText="Filter UserName column" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" UniqueName="UserName">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Email" FilterControlAltText="Filter Email column" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" UniqueName="Email">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

And in code-behind:

```
protected void RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
try
    {
       GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
       string username = Convert.ToString(dataItem["UserName"].Text);
       Label1.Text = "jkjh";

       MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username.ToString());
       Membership.DeleteUser(user.UserName.ToString(),true);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Please also add `SqlDataSource1` tag in your question ;).

Comment: TY man ... i got the solution with your comment. i needed a unique identifier in my sql server table.